# Google Tag Manager: update cookie value and fire tag if value has changed

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

I have the follow JS variable:

```js
function() {
  var products = [];
  prods.forEach(function(prod) {
    products.push(prod.ACode + '-' + prod.BCode);
  });
  return products.join('|');
}
```

The output is an array that contains codes like these:

C1K-DR|A2D-AH|B1T-S1|

These values are being pushed into a cookie. I'm simply struggling because when the value of the push changes, the cookie doesn't get updated.
After that, I would like to fire a tag based only IF this value has changed.

Thanks anyone who can help.

Comment: Looks like this cookie is used to keep track of a list of products? Why do you want to know if this list changed or not?

Comment: Correct. If the list changes, then I would like to start a new session and track the updated list of products. The cookie is basically used to block impressions. In other words, if the list remains unchanged, no matter any page refresh nor how much a user moves forward or backwards, then the tag doesn't fire.

Comment: The tags you're trying to trigger, are they Google Analytics tags?

Comment: Yes Google Analytics

Comment: GA will track sessions/pageviews different from how you've defined them. This will throw off your numbers.

Comment: Pageviews is not an issue, nor sessions as this is exactly what I am looking for. I'm fine with starting a new session, simply I'm struggling with the condition = IF the value of that cookie has changed.

Comment: I would suggest determining if the cookie's changed outside of GTM. Then trigger an event when it does change for GTM to pick up on.